# How can I render a 2-column title in the header of the Accordion component from React Native Paper?

Tags: react-native, flexbox, react-native-paper

I want to render a 2-column title in the header of the Accordion component from React Native Paper.

The design requires a controlled *group* of several accordions with each accordion's **title** property to be in the following format: displaying 2 separate pieces of text on 1 line, with some fixed space between them:

`XXXXXXXXXXXXXX               XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`

The idea is that the 2nd column of text in the header should line up with each accordion above & below.

I tried creating the list of titles using React-Native-Paper's [**DataTables**](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/data-table.html) and also with the stock React Native [**FlatList**](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist). Using the DataTables seemed a bit of overkill and I couldn't get it to align as desired so I tried the FlatList next and had better success with it--at least initially.

I rendered the FlatList using `flexDirection: 'row'` on the parent View and `flex: 3` & `flex: 4` on the 2 child Views.

*In isolation* it works as expected as you can see in [the following Snack example](https://snack.expo.dev/@groff0nthewall/flatlist-simple).

However, when passing a rendered **FlatList** to the title property of the [React-Native-Paper **List.Accordion**](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/list-accordion-group.html) it appears to lose the flex spacing [as shown in this Snack example](https://snack.expo.dev/@groff0nthewall/jobdashboard), so the 2nd column of header text does not align left.

**Any suggestions on how to achieve this?**

[image: A comparison of how I want the titles to render and how they are currently rendering]

For what it's worth, the client's request is this app will only ever be run on an Android Tablet, so iOS and phones are of no real concern.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able to "split" the `title` into multiple columns.

But, the `List.Accordion` actually has three columns built-in: `left`, `title` and `right`. You may be able to do something creative with this.